# Topological group and regularity of quotient space

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups

$G$ is a topological group. $H$ is a closed normal subgroup. Prove $G/H$ is a regular topological group.

In this question it can be easily proved that $G/H$ is a topological group, using the fact that $H$ is closed. How to prove the regularity of $G/H$?

Comment: How do you know that $G/H$ is even a group?

Comment: Sorry in my question H is a closed normal subgroup of G

Answer (score 1):

*Every* Hausdorff topological group is not only regular but, in fact, [completely regular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tychonoff_space). This is a consequence of the fact that every topological group has a natural [uniform structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_space).